# Array result to variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

i have a `php` script that result the following `array` sample below:

```
 {
          "success": true,
          "client": {
             "id": "1",
             "email": "jondoe@email.com",
             "password": "474bf122c92de249ace867a003cb7196",
             "lastlogin": "2011-11-25 04:32:40",
             "ip": "213.54.21.3",
             "host": "cmt-random.uk",
             "status": "Active",
             "parent_id": "0",
             "firstname": "John",
             "lastname": "Doe",
             "companyname": "",
             "address1": "Address 54",
             "address2": "",
             "city": "Soullans",
             "state": "Birmingham",
             "postcode": "B33 8TH",
             "country": "GB",
             "phonenumber": "357755733",
             "datecreated": "2011-09-24",
             "notes": "",
             "language": "spanish",
             "company": "0",
             "credit": "0.00",
             "taxexempt": "0",
             "latefeeoveride": "0",
             "cardtype": "Visa",
             "cardnum": null,
             "expdate": null,
             "overideduenotices": "0",
             "client_id": "1",
             "currency_id": "0",
             "countryname": "United Kingdom"
          },
          "call": "getClientDetails",
          "server_time": 1323442995
       }
```

My question is how to i put them to variable like
`$email = $client_email` above?

Comment: in php or in jquery? the above is json encoded array

Comment: Thanks Elen i actually solved with $email = $return->client->email;

Comment: PHP and Array, But that isn't an array. More looks like a json object to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was with this json array:  $email = $return->client->email;

Answer (score 1):

This is a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object, which means that you should be able to convert it into a PHP variable by using `json_decode`.

([See the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

In your example, this would be:

```
$data = json_decode($json_data);
```

If this rather needs to be used client-side, you will need to read this as a json object in order to access it correctly.

Comment: hmm right, didn't see that :) +1, I was lead by his keyword "array"

Comment: Thanks Fred, your solution does not work. i have got the solution  it should be : $email = $return->client->email;

Comment: @user2717872 Can you share your solution with us and provide more details into your question? My solution works, given that it is used the way I described in the answer, and given that I correctly understood your question.

Comment: $email = $return->client->email;

Answer (score 1):

Why the f* all these noobs are trying to use "extract"? Don't do it!
Just to stop this madness:

```
$data=json_decode($data,true);
$email= $data['client']['email'];
```

Comment: does not work OZ but thank you

Comment: Sorry but OZ's solution works fine, I just tried. As an additional note, you can either get json_decode() to return an object or an array <?php $data = json_decode($data); print $data->client->email; ?>

Comment: actually, you can even do that: `print json_decode($data)->client->email; `

Comment: Why are you so hostile with calling others noobs? unfortunately the post was a bit confusing, and even if it wasn't there is no need for such words. Lets just help the guy and that is all.

Comment: @xlordt because `export` is a very dangerous thing and should never be used.

Comment: Yeah it is dangerous, but only if you don't know what you are doing. I use it but I also have validation towards it to make sure that nothing has changed or have been overwritten. I its like using _POST/_GET with out sanitizing to me. Overall I do agree with ya.

Answer (score 0):

a PHP Array->variables is easiest done with `extract()`
like so:

```
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "client_"); //all keys in array will be extracted as
```

variables named client_keyname

However that doesn't look like a regular PHP array - so confirm your type!

Comment: `extract` is pretty brutal (and vulnerable), you shouldn't recommend it as a solution. There will always be a way to organize variables without using a bulldozer :)

Comment: as long as you are using EXTR_PREFIX_ALL and a even marginally unique non-blank prefix string how is it at all vulnerable? I can certainly see it as a brutal way but only vulnerable if poor security practice (like register_globals and no prefix) is followed. If this had been a true array rather than something else (as I noted) I would like to know what is the best way instead in your opinion?

Comment: I mean I can think of `list()` but if you don't know for certain which selection ofvariables are defined in the array it will get ugly for sure.

Comment: It's not really that it won't work, I only think that using such approach may affect the semantics of the code, since if you took enough time for conception you shouldn't have to rely on "it works anywhere" methods. For example, putting a `break` in a `for` statement. It works, always does. But it is semantically ugly and impossible to maintain / debug. I'd say the same for `eval`. It may look cool but most of the time it compensate a lack of competence.

Comment: But I agree with you that it's not vulnerable once you do what you said.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $array = array (
    "clients" => array (
        "id"      => 1,
        "name"  => "Dont know",
        "email" => "byteme@webyte.com",
 )
);

extract ($array ["clients"]);

echo $email (email is the arrays value);
```

**Edit** Did not realize his array was json, I was seduced by his array keyword.. please forgive me if this is not what was wanted.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood the issue is solved :-)

Comment: np, it happens. thank you for clearing.